# How to fix the non-existent blank SplashScreen issue on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-splashscreen

I am facing an issue of Android compatibility that warns me that there is a double splash screen, which is not true. I checked my implemenation and did not find any double splash screen. Also, there is only one splash screen to see when the app gets started.

Here is, how I implemented: `themes.xml`

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.<App_Name>" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

     <style name="Theme.<App_Name>.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">

         <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.<App_Name></item>
         <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/white</item>
         <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>

         <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.<App_Name>.SplashScreen"
    tools:targetApi="tiramisu">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.<App_Name>"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var isSplash = true

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition { isSplash }

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ isSplash = false }, 800)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Splash screen dependency version:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1") // The latest one.
```

Why does Play console warns that there is a doble splash screen? This warning appered in my very recent release upload. I had not that in previus releases.

Comment: Actually android recently introduced the default splash screen in every app, so if you have another one implemented then you get 2 of them, to avoid this you could either, remove yours and edit the default one, or there are ways in which you could bypass the default but they are not so good, tell if you want to know, and if this helped you.

Comment: The framework api might have been invoked earlier before the compat api you implemented kicks in.  Try calling `installSplashScreen()` before super.onCreate() as provided in compat splashscreen api doc.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal but that works for new android OS. Since my app supports old OS version, I use that API to make splash screen visible, too.

Comment: then you can bypass the new default one so that it's visible in old os too

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal how should I bypass? Thanks

Comment: It's not actually "officially" possible but you can add 
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>    
this in your main theme, but it will show a lag when the user clicks on your app, it's just a very clunky bypass, but if you want you could migrate your splash screen to the default andorid one using https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate

Comment: you can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/68110639/15214243 this discussion to see if you find any solutions, hope it helps

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal my implementation is according to the official documentation, isn't it? Or I miss something?

Comment: do you have another splash screen that you are running manually ?

Comment: Absolutly no, only that one proviced by `installSplashScreen()`. That's all.

Comment: So you're **only** implementing the default android splash screen, am I right?, If yes then I don't know the reason for there to be two splash screens.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal yes, I only customize the theme by addind icon and its background color. Actually, I do what the official documentation says.