# Delphi splash screen on Android 12

Tags: android, delphi

With Version 12, a new splash screen was introduced in Android as explained here:

> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

This results in the Delphi splash screen with the given image is not shown for my App anymore. I work with 10.4 Sydney, but I think the problem also applies to older versions of Delphi. Currently, I only see a blank page when the App starts, which is annoying. I guess in Delphi the current splash screen is not introduced by a seperate activity, but by a style? (This is option 2 in the link above)
This makes other hints found on Stackoverflow useless that give instructions to make the starting page at least transparent by modifying the style of the splash screen activity like here (or at least I did not get it working):

> [Disable Android 12 default splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921860/disable-android-12-default-splash-screen)

Has anyone found a solution to handle the new Android splash screen in Delphi, yet?

Comment: I have no solution yet either, but there is a Quality Portal report requesting support for this here:
[enter link description here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39331)